# qemu-system-aarch64: ../accel/tcg/cpu-exec.c:681: cpu_loop_exec_tb: Assertion `icount_enabled()' failed

Tags: qemu

I have compiled my qemu which version is 5.2.0 on mips64el host machine. When I run qemu-system-aarch64 to start a linux OS, I get this problem as follow:

```
qemu-system-aarch64: ../accel/tcg/cpu-exec.c:681: cpu_loop_exec_tb: Assertion `icount_enabled()' failed
```

Have anyone miss the same problem, please help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The -icount flag is buggy for a lot of QEMU architectures. <strike>I could not find if it is still supported in qemu</strike>. (As pointed out by [Peter Maydell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4499941/peter-maydell) it is properly supported). Try removing that flag for now and check if that works or not.

Also check if your device is supported [here](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM#Supported_in_qemu-system-aarch64).

Comment: icount is absolutely still supported. If you encounter bugs in it that reproduce with the current version of QEMU, please report them in the bug tracker : https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues with instructions on how to reproduce including QEMU commandline and any necessary image files.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen -- it is a bug in QEMU. You should confirm that you can reproduce it on a QEMU built from the head of upstream git, and then report it in the QEMU bug tracker at https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues with the full instructions on how to reproduce the failure, including the full QEMU command line and any image files that are needed.

It would also be helpful to check whether the problem reproduces on a different host architecture (eg x86-64) -- it may be that the bug is specific to running on MIPS hosts (we don't have good MIPS hosts that we can run CI testing on, so this setup gets a lot less testing).

Comment: I have post a issue with detail,[https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/496](https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/496). May it descrips my issue clearly.